# Vue 3 Fetching the data and passing to child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a page with several components in it, the data for all these components I need to get by making an ajax call.
As the child components are being mounted before the data comes in I'm getting undefined errors. Whats the best way to pass the data?

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-k1k9kx?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FIdChild.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FParent.vue,src%2FApp.vue)

In that example I have one Parent.vue and inside that we have 3 child coomponents, ID, Title, Body. After getting the data from API, the child componets are not updating.

Also for making the api calls I am directly calling load method inside setup() is there any better way of doing it?

Code Snippets from the stackblitz link

```
<template>
  <h1>Data from Parent</h1>
  {{ post.id }} - {{ post.title }} - {{ post.body }}
  <h1>Data from Child</h1>
  <IdChild :idP="post.id" />
  <TitleChild :titleP="post.title" />
  <BodyChild :bodyP="post.body" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const post = ref()
const load = async () => {
  let data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  post.value = await data.json()
}
load()
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with asynchronous data required in your components, you have basically two options:

1. You render the components before you get the data. It can be with default values or a loading state

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="!myAsyncData">Loading...</div>
  <div v-else>{{ myAsyncData }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const myAsyncData = ref(null)
async function load() {
  myAsyncData.value = await /* http call */
}

load() // will start to load and rendering the component
</script>
```

2. You await the response in the `setup` hook combined with the `<Suspense>` component so it starts to render only when the data is available.

Example ([playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-faejaa?file=src/components/Parent.vue)):

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <Parent />
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <div>{{ myAsyncData }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const myAsyncData = ref(null)
async function load() {
  myAsyncData.value = await /* http call */
}

await load() // will wait this before rendering the component. Only works if the component is embebbed within a [`<Suspense>`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html) component.
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kapcash in this example parent is a separate component which we wrapped with Suspense in App. In my actual project Parent is directly referred in router, any other suggestion we can implement suspense in this case, I tried giving suspense inside parent, but it didnt worked!

Comment: Wrap the `<RouterView/>` component then!